# Jenkins is not properly cloning git code in freestyle Jobs

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I have multiple freestyle jobs. In these jobs I am cloning the code from git. As shown below picture:

[source code management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc87N.png)

But sometimes the code doesn't want to be properly cloned from the repository.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Can anyone please help regarding this issue. It will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "sometimes the code doesn't want to be properly cloned from the repository": do you get an error message?

Comment: @VonC I didn't get any error. The job build & Deployed successfully. But Not reflected new changes made by developers in the application.

Comment: OK. In the job log (where the new changes made by developers were missing), do you see the right commit being checked out?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue before.
it's look like git do something like smart cloning which only clone the changes made to the repository.

issue resolved once i added an additional behavior to to `Wipe out repository & force clone` like below:
[image]